# UILocalNotification removed automatically

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I am working on VOIP iOS app in which i have to show a local notification when call comes and app is in background mode i make it like this

Register Notifications in appdelegate

```
UIUserNotificationType types            = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings  = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
```

showing Notification

```
if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState != UIApplicationStateActive) {
    UILocalNotification* localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif) {
        localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

        localNotif.alertTitle = @"Call From";
        localNotif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", callerName];
        localNotif.alertAction = @"Receive";
        localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

        localNotif.fireDate = [NSDate date];
        localNotif.userInfo = @{@"name":callerName};
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    }
}
```

the local notification show as alert on top but when user not attend the call or other user disconnect the call, local notification removed automatically from Notification centre which is very weird, i googled too much but no success suggest some solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you implement the registerUserNotificationSettings method?

Comment: yes in app delegate i register the notification first and then show notifications.

Comment: wow, never knew that is possible to remove notifications

Comment: I myself first time seeing issue like this, even i am using same code to show the notification in chat for showing message when app is in background and that works fine but here i am unable to understand why its behaving like this.